# How to paste many lines to a file using a bash script?

Tags: bash, bind, nis

I'm writing a script which will automatically configure a NIS client with the correct settings.
I'm trying to set the /etc/nsswitch.conf file and I'd like to overwrite whatever is already there with my settings.
Now my question is, how can I do that? how can i paste about 20 lines of settings into the client's nsswitch.conf file straight from the script?
I know i can do something like:

```
echo "line 1" > /etc/nsswitch.conf
echo "line 2" >> /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

But that's an ugly way to do it, I hope there is a better way to achieve this goal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [`cat`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat) together with [here-doc](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) syntax for this:

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/nsswitch.conf
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
...
EOF
```

The statement above will overwrite or create the file with the contents between the first line and `EOF`. In the form above even variables like `group:   $group` would be expanded by bash. If you don't want this, then use `<<'EOF'` (note the single quotes `'` around the `EOF`)

Comment: For reference, the `...` in the above example is illustrative only and not part of the syntax.